# How can I listen multiple ports via Elixir?

Tags: networking, network-programming, erlang, elixir, gen-tcp

I'd like to listen 2 ports via Elixir. I managed to listen the ports, though. However, I can't get data from second port.

```
  def accept() do
    {:ok, socket} = :gen_tcp.listen(7777, [:binary, packet: 0, active: false, reuseaddr: true])

    {:ok, httpSocket} =
      :gen_tcp.listen(8787, [:binary, packet: 0, active: false, reuseaddr: true])

    http_loop_acceptor(httpSocket)
    loop_acceptor(socket)
  end

  defp http_loop_acceptor(socket) do
    {:ok, client} = :gen_tcp.accept(socket)
    pid = spawn(fn -> http_serve(client) end)
    :ok = :gen_tcp.controlling_process(client, pid)
    http_loop_acceptor(socket)
  end

  defp loop_acceptor(socket) do
    {:ok, client} = :gen_tcp.accept(socket)
    pid = spawn(fn -> serve(client) end)
    :ok = :gen_tcp.controlling_process(client, pid)
    loop_acceptor(socket)
  end
```

I can send the data to **8787** port (httpSocket). However, I can't send any data to **7777** (socket).

If change the order of these 2 lines then I can send the data to **7777** (socket), I can't send any data to **8787** port.

```
http_loop_acceptor(httpSocket)
loop_acceptor(socket)
```

How can I listen multiple ports and receive data via those ports?

Answer (score 3):

In your `accept` function, the call to `http_loop_acceptor` will recurse infinitely, which means that `loop_acceptor` is never called.

If you want to listen on two sockets, you need to start two separate processes, one for each socket. A quick and dirty way is to use `spawn`, but in a real application you would model these processes as part of your supervision tree.

Comment: This is one of the hardest things to wrap ones head around when first coming over to Erlang/Elixir. It took me way to long to think like this.